# Add multiple items for one orderid in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, structure

I am trying to insert multiple items under one `orderid` into my database and I am stuck on how to do this.

My current db table structure:

```
order
orderid (auto increment)
productdesc
quantity
```

Current result in database (when items added from datagrid)

```
orderid   productdesc   quantity  
1         test          1          
2         value         2
3         demo          3
```

Desired result

```
orderid productdesc quantity
1       test        1  
1       value       2
1       demo        3
```

Is there a way to add the multiple items for one `orderid` before the next order comes which means the `orderid` would be 2. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you want ordered subgroups? Please post an example of what the table would look like after the insertion so we can be certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the items in a separate table, orderitems (or orderlines). The order table contains the main information about the order, and each item contains a product and it has an orderid that refers to the id of the main records. That orderid in orderitem is called a `foreign key`, because it refers to the `primary key` of another table.

```
orders
orderid   customer
(auto inc) 
1         John Doe
2         Jane Doe
3         Jim Doe

orderitems
orderitemid orderid   productdesc   quantity 
(auto inc)  (FK)
1           1         test          1          
2           1         value         2
3           1         demo          3
4           2         test          2
5           3         demo          1
6           3         value         1
```

So, when you want to insert an order, you insert one main record in `orders`, and a product in `orderitems`. When inserting an item, you will need to specify the orderid it belongs to. The database cannot know by itself which order you meant. You can keep adding items to it, even after you've created a new order, as long as you know the orderid of the order you want to modify.

And you can get that id using [MySQL's function `last_insert_id`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). So the steps are:

- Insert order
- Get id of order
- Insert item(s)

Then, to query all items for an order, you can query it like this:

```
select
  o.orderid,
  o.customer
  oi.orderitemid,
  oi.productdesc,
  oi.quantity
from
  orders o
  inner join orderitems oi on oi.orderid = o.orderid
where
  o.orderid = 1
```

Or, if you need just the items:

```
select
  oi.orderitemid,
  oi.orderid,
  oi.productdesc,
  oi.quantity
from
  orderitems oi
where
  oi.orderid = 1
```

It's a matter of preference whether you want to give the orderitems an id as well. I think it's good to give a table like that a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) as well, but it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: But if you see my orderid is auto-increment... how can i set it so each order has one id.

Comment: You can add multiple items to one order by putting the items in a separate table. In that table, `orderid` should not be auto-increment. I've added some more explanation. In short, a database is more than a single table. In a real-life sample. You'll have separate tables for customer, order, orderitem, and possibly payments, shipments, addresses....

Comment: so on the intial insert, I need to run two insert scripts first in orders and then orderitems?

Comment: Indeed. In most databases you can get the id of the last records you just inserted, and you can use that id to insert the item.

Comment: Ok, I will try this and granting it work will accept as answer :)